# Finding similar rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my db with song titles.  There are several duplicates, but are slightly off.  For instance, my table might look like this:

```
id  title
1   Photobooth
2   Photobooth [*]
3   Photobooth [dvd]
4   Photobooth [acoustic]
5   Song for Kelly Huckaby
6   Song for Kelly Huckaby [*]
```

I am trying to break this down so my results would look like:

```
1   Photobooth
5   Song for Kelly Huckaby
```

How should I be handling this query?  Strip out everything within [] and then finding dups?

Comment: Do the "slightly-off" entries always end with a `[...]`? You could probably use some regex function to eliminate everything that ends with `\[.*\]$` and perform a `GROUP BY` on the resulting set. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: Yessir, the majority of different track versions are within [...] format.  There are a handful that don't follow this formatting, but I'm comfortable with handling these one-offs manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN LOCATE('[', title)-1 = -1
                      THEN TRIM(title)
                      ELSE TRIM(LEFT(title, LOCATE('[', title)-1))
                END title
FROM table1
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96a99/6)

Comment: Lets say we had another row, id 7 title This Love.  This row does not have any other versions.  Is there a way to then exclude this row from the results?

Comment: yes, you mean you want only to return records that has multiple version? please wait, i will update the answer.

Comment: @Mike [SQLFiddle Demo (click here)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cadf9/1 "link created by totet")